# Postgresql won't connect to server following re-install in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I am running Ubunutu 14.04. I recently purged postgresql from my system and have re-installed it. The installation seemed successful and the postgres user was created successfully, however, when I attempt to launch psql I get the following error:

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @fvu ps ax | grep gives:
10831 pts/0    S      0:00 su postgres
11786 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep postgres

Comment: ... which means that your postgres service isn't running. As a test, start it manually (something like `sudo service postgresql start`), if that works, check your manual to see how to autostart a service on each boot.

Comment: No that's still not working.

Comment: do you see a postgres process running in px ax now?

Comment: Doesnt't look like it
3152 pts/2    S      0:00 su postgres
3177 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep postgres

Comment: So it did not start.  Check its logging, normally in /var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

I removed postgresql 9.4 again and replaced it with the previous version. Everything appears to be working now, though this is a somewhat unsatisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reinstall the postgresql-9.6.x ?

Me too...

You need to uninstall postgresql completely

`sudo apt --purge autoremove postgresql*`

`sudo apt install postgresql-9.6`

ubuntu16.04